# pip or pip3 for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This is probably a dumb question, but does it matter if you're running pip3? I ask as when I try to install something with pip install {package name} it tells me I don't have pip, but I am able to install packages with pip3.

I am confused where everything gets installed on macOS.

Comment: On a Mac, if you used Homebrew to install Python3, you can check "*where everything gets installed*" using `brew info python3`.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your OS. For OSes where `python` means Python 2, `pip` *typically* (but not always) means "pip for Python 2", while `pip3` means "pip for Python 3".

If you want to avoid ambiguity over which Python you're running `pip` with, don't run `pip` *or* `pip3`. Run `python -mpip` (replacing `python` with the name of the Python interpreter you want to use), which will run the `pip` module installed for that interpreter, rather than hoping `pip3` is for what you run as `python3`, when it might be that `python3` is for Python 3.8, while `pip3` is installed for Python 3.7 or the like.

If you're looking for where stuff is being pulled from, running a script that just does `print(sys.path)` should show you where it looks for stuff. Individual installed modules typically have a `__file__` attribute you can inspect after importing them.

Comment: To add to an excellent answer, if you use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), `pip` will always be the correct `pip`.

Comment: A good reference: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: thanks so much for the link, I see if I use python3.8 -m pip I am using python 3.8 :)